# can't be indexed twice - testSourceDirectory and sourceDirectory are same

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have created performance test as a maven submodule to my main module. All the test classes are written under src/**main**/java and not src/**test**/java

I am able to package the project as jar and run it to performance test my project.

I wanted to execute `mvn test`. For `mvn test` to work I should have `<testSourceDirectory>` value set. As in this case I have my code in src/main/java I set this to :

```
<testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

Now `mvn test` works.

But the Problem is sonar build fails with error complaining: `can't be indexed twice`. Which is obvious as for my pom `testSourceDirectory` and `sourceDirectory` are same.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) 
   on project Blah: File [relative=XYZ.java, abs=/Path/XYZ.java] can't be indexed twice. 
Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce 
disjoint sets for main and test files ->
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Some logs may be ? 'file already indexed' is a rather scarce information.

Comment: Updated the question with the exact error.

Answer (score 25):

I was facing the same problem. Finally, solved it with help of below documentation:-

https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/FAQ

> **Q: ERROR: Caused by: File [...] can't be indexed twice.**
>
> A: In case of below error you have to verify your exclusion/inclusion
>   properties. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce
>   disjoint sets for source and test files
>
> ERROR: Caused by: File [...] can't be indexed twice. Please check that
>   inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test
>   files An example could look like this:
>
> ```
> sonar.sources=.
> sonar.tests=.
> sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
> sonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/**
> ```

Answer (score 5):

This is not a standard Maven usage but you can easily fix SonarQube analysis using exclusions.
sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/**
or
sonar.test.exclusions=src/main/java/**

depending on whether you want your source files to be considered as tests or main files.

But the proper Maven way would be to put your tests in src/test/java and ackage your tests:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

Comment: put `sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/**` or `sonar.test.exclusions=src/main/java/**` in `sonar.properties` and restart the sonar server? Still its not working for me, seeing the same exception

Comment: Turns out that I had `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` in pom.xml and that was the issue

Comment: @AnandRockzz you saved my days. I had also same config in build.gradle file. :)

Answer (score 0):

If project does not follow default Maven directory structure then in project's pom you can explicitly specify where is located the part of source code and the part of tests:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.sources>src/main/foo</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test/bar</sonar.tests>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this `can't be indexed twice` error when running `sonarqube` Gradle task on an Android project. The issue related to files stored in `app/src/debug/assets`.

I tried setting `sonar.sources` and `sonar.tests` properties to use disjointed sets but I wasn’t able to resolve the error.

To fix the error I changed:

```
property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "**/assets/**, ..."
```

to:

```
property "sonar.exclusions", "**/assets/**, ..."
```

in order to ignore the /assets/ directory completely.