# Sonar error in multi language project: File can't be indexed twice

Tags: java, javascript, maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to setup sonar to analyze both java and javascript sources.
I have a standard structure maven project.
Following [THIS](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-java-javascript-maven) example I've added the line

```
<properties>
    <sonar.sources>src</sonar.sources>
</properties>
```

But when I run

> mvn clean install sonar:sonar

I get the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project myproject: File [moduleKey=myproject:myproject,
>   relative=src/test/java/com/myproject/api/v1/ControllerTest.java,
>   basedir=C:\sources\project] can't be indexed twice. Please check that
>   inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test
>   files -> [Help 1]

"ControllerTest.java" is the first file in the /src/test/java/../.. folder

project structure:

[image]

Any hints? Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE

1#
Tried Akash Rajbanshi suggestion: error disappeared but js code is not analyzed and also sonar doesn't analyze the test folder

2# tried to put `<sonar.language>js</sonar.language>` and the js code is actually analyzed but java code is not (that was just a test)

I'm kind of stuck

Comment: Hey @Manza. Did find out how to resolve issue?

Comment: Kind of. Not really.
I had to run the build 2 times, one with parameter language set to js and one with java.

Comment: I just resolve the same issue. Your project are with multiple Maven modules?

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40150551/375953

Answer (score 2):

In order to make SonarQube analyse your tests as well, you should also set the "sonar.tests" property:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
<properties>
   <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
</properties>
```

Comment: where are ur js files?

Comment: in src/main/webapp/public

Comment: What happens if you include both `<sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>` and `<sonar.language>js</sonar.language>`

Comment: oh i see...the java sources and test are not analyzed right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78212/discussion-between-manza-and-akash-rajbanshi).