# Can not make script 'run-sonar-swift' works

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarlint

I am trying to run sonar swift.
I have already sonarQube with the plugin and I can access it locally using this url http://localhost:9000 . I have installed all prerequisites that you can find here :

https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift

But I can't figure out what is this error when i launch run-sonar-swift.sh.

If anyone can bring me the light I would be very grateful.

Here the logs when I run in terminal command **./run-sonar-swift.sh -v** :

> MacBook-Air:streamus-phoenix-ios oboujaouane$ ./run-sonar-swift.sh -v
>
> Running run-sonar-swift.sh...
>
> Project count is [1]
>
> Xcode project file is: Streamus.xcodeproj
>
> Xcode workspace file is: Streamus.xcworkspace
>
> Xcode application scheme is: Streamus Alpha
>
> Destination simulator is: platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=11.3
>
> Excluded paths from coverage are: .*Tests.*
>
> Creating directory sonar-reports/
>
> Running tests
>   + xcodebuild clean build test -workspace Streamus.xcworkspace -scheme 'Streamus Alpha' -configuration Debug -enableCodeCoverage YES -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=11.3' -destination-timeout 60
>
> 2018-05-12 10:34:14.031 xcodebuild[32149:775290]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
>   /var/folders/9v/vdbbf4j96hxgcxmtpntznytr0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-9A7EF764-6391-4C7D-9F34-066A9DFEC5E9/StreamusUITests-87E838E0-4F8F-4C19-B2AC-C2C0A274E8EC/Session-StreamusUITests-2018-05-12_103414-jhm3wz.log
>
> 2018-05-12 10:34:14.032 xcodebuild[32149:769805] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (98FB295E-FE60-46AA-8589-015B0DD2E617) Beginning test session StreamusUITests-98FB295E-FE60-46AA-8589-015B0DD2E617 at 2018-05-12 10:34:14.031 with Xcode 9E145 on target  {
>           SimDevice: iPhone 6 (672DE879-E48B-45DA-BFD9-D0412F51A706, iOS 11.3, Booted)
>   } (11.3 (15E217))
>
> 2018-05-12 10:34:14.061 xcodebuild[32149:769805] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (458F86F6-1492-40F1-9F72-A88FC23BD985) Beginning test session StreamusTests-458F86F6-1492-40F1-9F72-A88FC23BD985 at
>
> 2018-05-12 10:34:14.061 with Xcode 9E145 on target  {
>           SimDevice: iPhone 6 (672DE879-E48B-45DA-BFD9-D0412F51A706, iOS 11.3, Booted)
>   } (11.3 (15E217))
>
> 2018-05-12 10:34:14.061 xcodebuild[32149:770075]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
>   /var/folders/9v/vdbbf4j96hxgcxmtpntznytr0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-9A7EF764-6391-4C7D-9F34-066A9DFEC5E9/StreamusTests-4F203461-1372-49B7-A806-F130F168079E/Session-StreamusTests-2018-05-12_103414-MfIreE.log
>   2018-05-12 10:34:30.016 xcodebuild[32149:769805]
>
> Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=14 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9v/vdbbf4j96hxgcxmtpntznytr0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-9A7EF764-6391-4C7D-9F34-066A9DFEC5E9/StreamusUITests-87E838E0-4F8F-4C19-B2AC-C2C0A274E8EC/Session-StreamusUITests-2018-05-12_103414-jhm3wz.log"
>
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9v/vdbbf4j96hxgcxmtpntznytr0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-9A7EF764-6391-4C7D-9F34-066A9DFEC5E9/StreamusUITests-87E838E0-4F8F-4C19-B2AC-C2C0A274E8EC/Session-StreamusUITests-2018-05-12_103414-jhm3wz.log}
>
> 2018-05-12 10:34:30.016 xcodebuild[32149:769805] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=14 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9v/vdbbf4j96hxgcxmtpntznytr0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-9A7EF764-6391-4C7D-9F34-066A9DFEC5E9/StreamusTests-4F203461-1372-49B7-A806-F130F168079E/Session-StreamusTests-2018-05-12_103414-MfIreE.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9v/vdbbf4j96hxgcxmtpntznytr0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-9A7EF764-6391-4C7D-9F34-066A9DFEC5E9/StreamusTests-4F203461-1372-49B7-A806-F130F168079E/Session-StreamusTests-2018-05-12_103414-MfIreE.log}
>
> Testing failed:
>       Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   ** TEST FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> Ld /Users/oboujaouane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Streamus-gwtdwpbaxrfgafdtejzjtpxyhhhq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Streamus.build/Alpha-iphonesimulator/StreamusTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/StreamusTests normal x86_64
>
> Ld /Users/oboujaouane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Streamus-gwtdwpbaxrfgafdtejzjtpxyhhhq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Streamus.build/Alpha-iphonesimulator/StreamusTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/StreamusTests normal i386
>
> (2 failures)
>
> - returnValue=65
> - set +x
>
> ERROR - Command 'xcodebuild clean build test -workspace Streamus.xcworkspace -scheme Streamus Alpha -configuration Debug -enableCodeCoverage YES -destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=11.3 -destination-timeout 60' failed with error code: 65

In advance thank you,

Comment: Are you sure you have the given simulator installed?

Comment: Yes I am sure of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It seems that error was due to provisioning profile. When I added my Provisioning Profile and try it again the problem was resolved.
2. Then I had another problem with MessageKit:“Segmentation fault: 11”
   It was a CocoaPods Podfile config issue.
   So I had to switch compilation mode for Debug from "Single File" to "Whole Module” by click on Pods in Xcode project navigator then select MessageKit in targets of pods then Builds settings tab then in searcher tap ‘compilation mode’ and switch “Single File” to “Whole Module” and re-run script run-sonar-swift.sh

￼[image: Here how to switch to Whole Module instead of Single File]

⚠️ each time you make a pod install / update or something that can change pods you have to switch compilation mode for Debug from "Single File" to "Whole Module” for the pod which give you an error when you launch run-sonar.swift.sh with -v for verbose.

3. After that it was not yet the end of my problems! In fact I had a last problem which was an error with SwipeCellKit pod: “No such module SwipeCellKit”. To resolve this problem follow instructions given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37732248/6188918
4. Then I tried again and the rest of the script started (SwiftLint, Tailor & Lizard) and I thought this time it was finally good but an error occurred once again a new error message at the end of the script concerning Lizard which was:

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>
> ERROR: File
>   MyprojectName/Domains/Repositories/Local/cacheManager.swift can't be
>   indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce
>   disjoint sets for main and test files
>
> ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full
>   debug logging.

To resolve this inclusion/exclusion I followed the answer given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40150551/6188918
by adding these to line in sonar-project.properties file below sonar.swift.excludedPathsFromCoverage line:

> sonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
>
> sonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/**

I tried again but with parameter -notailor(run script and skip Tailor):

> ./run-sonar-swift.sh -notailor -v

just to save a little time because tailor take time

5. And after launch the script... Boom a new error... But it was a known issue:

> Error: Caused by: org.sonar.api.measures.PersistenceMode

And the issue is explained here https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift/issues/118

So I downloaded this .jar file “backelite-sonar-swift-plugin-0.4-sonar-7-quick-fix.jar” found here https://github.com/Hugal31/sonar-swift/releases/tag/0.4-sonar-7-quick-fix  and replace it in plugins of my local SonarQube and try again.

…and this time after an umpteenth launch I finally saw the light

Hope this answer will help and if you have a question don’t hesitate.
  Good luck & have fun :)

PS: You’ll find here some options to run script with parameters:

> ./run-sonar-swift.sh -noswiftlint -v (run script with verbose option  and skip SwiftLint)
>
> ./run-sonar-swift.sh -notailor -v (run script with verbose option and skip Tailor)
>
> ./run-sonar-swift.sh -nounittests -v (if your project does not have scheme configured to be tested launch with this parameter)

If you want more info check in run-sonar-swift.sh script and check around lines 125 ## COMMAND LINE OPTIONS

PS2: I have also opened an issue in sonar-swift GitHub if it can help: https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift/issues/138

Comment: `It seems that error was due to provisioning profile. When I added my Provisioning Profile and try it again the problem was resolved. ` what you did exactly? facing exactly same error

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra issue with oclint: `oclint: Not enough positional command line arguments specified!`. So I had to modify the `run-sonar-swift.sh` script a little bit in order to get it working: https://gist.github.com/Edudjr/79a2379842357c33709aecf040d9ae77#file-run-sonar-swift-sh

And this is a model of my sonar-project.properties: https://gist.github.com/Edudjr/db51907068ea76b116d11d9a9b13f05f#file-sonar-project-properties

Comment: what changes have you made?